# How to make sure microservices interactions via kafka I think up are correct?

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, scalability

Imagine I have a microservice which emits kafka event and microservice handler would handle it via kafka listener. Handlers microservice should scale and I believe I should do it via kafka group ids in my streams but I don't understand mechanism of how other handlers will not process emitted kafka event if one microservice had already started to process one. Could you please help me with understanding it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the same consumer group, by giving them all the same groupdId. In that way only one of them will be able to consume each of the messages

you can read more about it [here](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#intro_consumers)